# How can I use flying saucer to show an image that takes up the full top of a page?

Tags: itext, flying-saucer, margin

I'm attempting to use flying saucer with itext 5 to create a pdf that contains text as well as some images that take up the entire top half of the page, including margins.  Using css properties for width and height, and by making the image float, I can get the image to show up on the top of the page, but it is still (of course) within the margins of the page.  When I try to circumvent this with, say

```
margin-top: -1in;
```

The image is moved not into the margin of the current page, but into the previous page.

How can I make the image move into the page margins?

Answer (score 2):

If your image is defined in the `body` of the HTML page, I don't know any way to move it into the margins.

However, you can define your image as the background of the page.

This would be something  like:

```
@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 20mm; 
    background-image:url('http://xxx/your-image.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat
}
```

In this case the logo is placed at the top left of the page starting inside the margins.

Note that even with the `no-repeat` option, the image is repeated on each page of the PDF document.

---

If you need to display the image only on the first page, I would suggest another approach: define a specific header for the first page.

For example like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
   @page {
       size: A4;
       margin: 25mm; 
   }
   /* Display header only on first page */
   @page :first {
       @top-center {content: element(header);}
   }    
   #header {
       position: running(header);
       height:25mm;
       margin-left:-25mm;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
       <img src="http://xxx/your-image.png" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The header will starts in the margin and spans on the body of the page. As it is only defined for the first page, it won't be repeated.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but that particular trick won't serve my purposes, since I'll need the image to appear only once.

Comment: Fortunately, I thought about an alternative since I post my first answer. I've updated it, and I hope it will solve your problem.